# What are necessary conditions for taking Union of two datasets in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, union, apache-spark-dataset

What are necessary conditions like no of columns or identical columns or different columns

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the you have two dataframes.

```
  val df1 = spark.sql("SELECT 1 as a,3 as c")
  val df2 = spark.sql("SELECT 1 as a,2 as b")
```

df1.union(df2) - will work, because it`s conditions is the same number of columns

```
df1.union(df2).show()
+---+---+
|  a|  c|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```

as you can see it takes df1 columns, and match only by the index of the columns of df2, and not by the name.

if you are using unionByName, e.g

```
  df1.unionByName(df2).show()
```

it wouldn`t work because it try look for 'c' column in df2.

to sum up, both union style needs the same number of columns.
unionByName - required that the columns will be at the same name too.